# Show me how this output comes

Tags: c++

Here is my code :

```
for(int x=1;x<=5;x++) {
    for(int x=0;x<=1;x+=1) {
        cout<<"###############"<<endl;
    }
}
```

Why it prints 10 lines like this:

```
    ###############
    ###############
    ###############
    ###############
    ###############
    ###############
    ###############
    ###############
    ###############
    ###############
```

If I run each loop alone, it will print 5 lines for the first loop and 2 lines for the second loop. How this 2 loops run together?

Comment: Debugger.  Use a debugger.  A debugger will allow you to single step through your program, *watching* values and variables and tracing execution flow.  Often, using a debugger is faster than correctly posting to StackOverflow and waiting for somebody to inspect your code or somebody to debug your program for you.

Comment: Analogy: I have taken the medicine *twice* a day for *five* days. How many times have I taken in total?

Comment: No, the first *for loop* will run the second *for loop* `5` times. Each time the second *for loop* will print `2` lines.

Comment: Recommendation: Don't nest a loop which uses the same variable name. The second eclipses the first, making the first non-accessible, and also makes it very to follow what is happening in large code

Answer (score 0):

Try adding some diagnostic printing statements:

```
for(int x=1;x<=5;x++)
{
    cout << "--> x before inner loop" << x << endl;
    for(int x=0;x<=1;x+=1)
    {
        cout << "--> x in inner loop" << x << endl;
        cout<<"###############"<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, rush typing. :-(

Answer (score 0):

You have nested for-loop, The outer loop will run from x=1 to x=5 (5 iterations)
and your inner loop runs from x=0 to x=1 (2 iterations), where every loop prints "###############".

For each iteration of the outer loop, you run the inner loop 2 times. Hence, 5 iterations produce 5*2 = 10 lines.

Just as a good programming practice, keep your control variables different. 
i.e.

```
// outer loop
for(int x=1; x<=5; x++){
    // inner loop
    for(int j=0; j<=1; j+=1){
        cout << "###############" << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int x=1;x<=5;x++)
{
    for(int x=0;x<=1;x+=1)
    {
        cout<<"###############"<<endl;
    }
}
```

Think about this: Assume you write 2 lines per day and you keep doing the work for five days, you will have written 10 lines by then.

If you're thinking why it shouldn't be 5 or 7, that's because the `int x=0` at line 3 ["hides"](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/unqualified_lookup#Namespace_scope) the outer `x`, so the two variable `x`'s are isolated from each other, and they don't conflict.